# Window resize does not take effect on css

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I'm using jQuery to invoke a window resize - the event definitely fires.

The event I'm firing adds some css to a div which controls the size and position of the main webpage.

However, what I'm finding is that the "reset" doesn't work in certain circumstances and I can't understand why.

```
$window.on("resize", onResize);

    function onResize() {
        $page.css({
            "margin-left": "",
            "width": ""
        });

        fixPagePosition();
    }

    function fixPagePosition() {
        var left = $page.offset().left;
        var width = $page.outerWidth();

        $page.css({
            "margin-left": left,
            "width": width
        });
    }
```

The code above works - which is what I would expect, however, the onResize function needs to reset the css before the actual positioning takes place.

If I remove the following code, co-ordinates are not recalculated and the page is not positioned correctly. The removal of the css first seems like a bit of a hack.

```
$page.css({
            "margin-left": "",
            "width": ""
        });
```

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: You want the $page to reset while resizing? And when done resizing it should fixPagePosition?

Comment: $page is a container that is positioned centrally within the viewport. The co-ordinates ensure it stays where it is when a modal window is opened and the body scroll is disabled. If you were viewing on a mobile or tablet and change the orientation, the positions should recalculate - repositioning in the new centre of the page. It does not do this without first removing the original css.

Comment: It would really help if you could make a jsFiddle

Comment: I believe that $page properties are cached or not recalculated at the time `fixPagePosition` is called. The 'reset' css forces a cache-bust, that is why it is working.